# Deleting elements in a list by their value as index

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension

I have a list which is days in a time series that doesn't start at zero:

```
days = [2,3,4,5,...]
```

I have another list which is minutes of cloud on all days starting at day 0:

```
weather = [0,120,150,60,120,30,300,...]
```

I want to iterate through `days`, and remove it if the corresponding index in `weather` is greater than some value.

I've tried

```
downtime = 100
days_new = [x for i, x in enumerate(days) if weather[i] < downtime]
```

Which should then result in:

```
days_new = [3,5,...]
```

as the indexes removed (2,4) have a value greater than 100 in the list `weather`.

But it's removing them based off the *index* of `days` not its value as an index. I.e. this only works if my list starts at 0, not any integer greater than 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: @ChristianDean Because they are keeping those at indices `<`.

Comment: The code you posted should work.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Ah, I see what he meant. It was a bit confusing the way he stated it.

Comment: Unless the two lists are *out of sync* in which case you have to do `days_new = [x for i, x in enumerate(days) if weather[i + 2] < downtime]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement assumes `weather` is *subscriptable* by all the items in `days`, in which case you wouldn't need `enumerate`. Index `weather` directly with the indices in `days`:

```
days_new = [x for x in days if weather[x] < downtime]
```

Answer (score 1):

If weather is given for all days and day from `days` is an index in weather:

```
downtime = 100
new_days = [day for day in days if weather[day] <= downtime]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
[x for x in days if weather[x] <= 100]
```

Output, for your input:

```
[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
days = [2,3,4,5,...]
weather = [0,120,150,60,120,30,300,...]
downtime = 100
days_new = []
for x in days:
    if weather[x] < downtime:
        days_new.append(x)

# output :
days_new = [3, 5,...]
```